# Linux module to deny write permissions to BIOS?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86, bios

Can a Linux module be written that denies write permissions to the BIOS? (I assume that there is no legitimate reason for write permissions unless you are flashing the BIOS.) What can I query to get the BIOS port? Is that port used only for the BIOS or is it multi-purpose? Is there a system call that can be overridden to check for write permissions on that particular port?

Comment: I don't think the BIOS is normally writable anyway, as it's stored on a ROM chip.

Comment: @Drew McGowen I want to stop BIOSRootkits. How can I deny write permissions?

Comment: I'm more than certain there's no simple way to do it, as BIOS-related stuff is usually chipset-specific. You'd have to look for documentation (if there is any) for your particular chipset.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen - *"the BIOS is ... stored on a ROM chip"* - Since the mid 1990's, the BIOS has been stored in FLASH memory, which can be electronically erased and rewritten.  Flash memory is not considered ROM.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Flashing the BIOS is typcially done not by using some driver but by accessing the SPI or I²C controller hardware directly.

Some mainboards have hardware write protection switches/jumpers.
Neither the kernel nor a rootkit could do anything about that.

Some flash chips have a write protection that can only be enabled, but cannot be disabled without a reset, i.e., only the BIOS can do or allow flashing.
Neither the kernel nor a rootkit could do anything about that.

On most mainboards, the flash hardware has no write protection.
There is nothing the kernel can do about that; any rootkit that has the capability to access the hardware is already in complete control and is also able to reverse any software protection measures attempted by the kernel.